# using C++ 2010 dll in excel

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, excel, dll

Ive built a simple dll in c++ using Visual C++ 2010 and am trying to use it in excel. The project name is "SwapFunDLL", the source files name is "swapmain" and the name of the header file containing the class and its function is "DateNTime". Ive attached them below. The code takes in two values and then uses the class function to multiply them and then returns the product (i realize the class and function arent necessary, im just doing this to learn). The function compiles with not errors however when the function is used in excel i get a value error. Could someone please help me see what im doing wrong thanks.

header:

```
// DateNTime.h

//Avoid need of .Def file    
#ifdef SwapFunDLL_EXPORTS
#define SwapFunDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define SwapFunDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)   
#endif

namespace DateNTime
{
    class SwapFunDLL_API Date
    {
        double x,y;
     public:
        double datediff(double,double);
     };

    double Date::datediff(double x, double y)
    {
        return x*y;
    }
}
```

Source File:

```
#include "DateNTime.h"
namespace DateNTime
{
   double returndates(double a, double b)
   {
       Date Date;
       return Date.datediff(a,b);
   }
 }
```

Excel Macro:

`Declare Function SwapFunDLL _ 
Lib "C:\Users\MIKE\Desktop\c++ tial programs\SwapFunDLL\Debug\SwapFunDLL.dll" _
(ByRef x As Double, ByRef y As Double) As Double`

Comment: have you declared exported functions in .def file?

Comment: I dont have a .def file. From what I understood the use of the __deslspec(dllexport) keyword eliminated the need to list functions in a DEF file.

Comment: yes, but you can have .defs file in any case. also make all your functions static

Comment: I don't know much about Excel macros, but the ByRef in the parameter list looks wrong. I think you should pass your arguments ByVal instead.

Answer (score 0):

your import declaration is wrong. Two things: the semantics and declaration of types. If you use pointers than in Excel you say `ByRef`, but if you use by value passing you say `ByVal`.
Declare this function as:

```
Declare Function returndates Lib "C:\Users\MIKE\Desktop\c++ tial programs\SwapFunDLL\Debug\SwapFunDLL.dll" _ (ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double) As Double
```

**make your function returndates member of your class that is being exported**, static member. 
also make your function static and in any case you can declare this export in .def file (just simply: "returdates" it's all). After all of it this has to work unless your C++ code is OK.
also here:

```
   double returndates(double a, double b)
   {
       Date Date; //<- change it, i.e: Date d; d.datediff(); does it compile? 
       return Date.datediff(a,b);
   }
```

you can change the code just to test if you do everything correctly to such "test info" form:

```
   double returndates(double a, double b)
   {
       return 117;
   }
```

and try it in Excel.
Excel needs `__stdcall`, so make a functions declarations inside your class like this:

```
static double __stdcall returndates(double a, double b);
```

then define it in .cpp file as:

```
    SwapFunDLL_API double __stdcall DateNTime::Date::returndtes(double a, double b){
      return 117;
      }
```

after all these changes should be OK.

Comment: So i made the member function static as well as the "returndates" function. i changed to ByVal in the excel Macro and I created a DEF file which has the following:

LIBRARY "SwapFunDLL"
EXPORTS
returndates

This caused the program to no longer build

Comment: put there only the name of exported function

Comment: k changed, its building again but still no luck in making it work in excel (still a value error)

Comment: see edit, and be sure that function works at all as C++ function

Comment: im sorry, i dont understand

Comment: ya refreshed the page and saw your edit....so i implemented your changes and it builds successfully

Comment: sadly still no luck on getting excel to see use the function

Comment: does Excel see this function? when you start typing =retu.. does it do code completion?

Comment: have you changed it to return simple constant?

Comment: also make your function returndates member of your class that is being exported, I haven't noticed it before, ofcourse it has to be member of exported class

Comment: Are we talking about the memeber function? No i thought i was already set to return a double

Comment: yes, is returndates a member function? if not, make it member, doesn't change anything, and in my DLL works

Comment: No returndates isnt a member. Only datediff is a member function of class Date....what should returndates be a member function of?

Comment: you don't need returndates, you can use just datediff. you export class Date and its functions

Comment: i tried using the testinfo form and even that doesnt work. I included the __stdcall and the def file. not sure what i did wrong