# #VAL! answers when trying to call a simple c++ program from excel with DLL

Tags: c++, excel, dll

I'm quite new to c++ and really new to creating DLL files. As a training excercise I tried to create a simple excel function that multiplies input data with 12. However excel keeps throwing up value errors.

I think I'm having a problem similar to [using C++ 2010 dll in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005375/using-c-2010-dll-in-excel). I followed the instructions in www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~ahazel/EXCEL_C++.pdf  to create the code and when it didn't work I simplified it further.

my cpp file is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

static int  _stdcall Multiply(int x)
{
    int a = 12;
    return a*x;
}
```

My DEF file is:

```
LIBRARY DLLtest
EXPORTS
Multiply
```

And lastly my VBA code is:

```
Declare Function Multiply _
Lib "C:\Users\[path]\Debug\DLLtest.dll" _
(ByVal x As Integer) As Integer
```

edit: I should probably add that I'm using excel 2010 and visual studio express 2013. The c++ code also came with some prebuilt code in dllmain.cpp and stdafx.cpp but I'm assuming this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you have to change options in the compiler/project to make it understand how to use the def file and the DLL.
[This site](https://sites.google.com/site/jrlhost/links/excelcdll) gives a pretty good explanation.